# Select max value without group by

Tags: sql

I need to help to get a max value for each id. Simple table is just shown below,

```
ID        Value      
---------------
111        150         
112        110         
111        100         
113        120         
115        130     
111        180
112        190
```

What I want too see in the output:

```
ID        Value      
---------------
111        180       
112        190        
111        180        
113        120        
115        130 
111        180
112        190
```

I do not want to group by each id, I want all of them in the output.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want window functions:

```
select t.*, max(value) over (partition by id) as max_id
from t;
```

This answers the question.  I'm not sure what the sample data has to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use the `MAX` function at all then you can use the `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT Y.ID, R.VALUE
FROM YOUR_TABLE Y
JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT ID, VALUE
         FROM YOUR_TABLE T
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                             FROM YOUR_TABLE TT
                            WHERE TT.ID = T.ID
                              AND TT.VALUE > T.VALUE
                         ) 
     ) R ON Y.ID = R.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also correlated subquery in the SELECT list:

```
SELECT
    id,
    (SELECT
        max(value)
    FROM
        tbl t2
    WHERE
        t2.id = t1.id) AS value
FROM
    tbl t1
```